# Auto Focus Form Element on iPhone/iPad

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, ipad

I'm trying to create a web application that automatically focuses the text input box upon page load.

However, I know that the 'autofocus' attribute isn't supported in mobile safari. The reason I need it to autofocus is because I am developing a web application so to say, and it basically requires the user to use their bluetooth scanner to send input to a PHP page that then POSTs that data (and hence, leaves the page briefly). Upon return, I wish for the box to be focused again, ready for the next scan. And as you may have guessed, my client wishes to use an iPad/iPhone.

The input is essentially just a keyboard wedge, a series of keyboard strokes will be sent wherever the focus is.

I've tried using the JavaScript and jQuery code below to no avail;

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#scan-input" ).focus();
});
```

Didn't work. And;

```
function formfocus() {
    document.getElementById('scan-input').focus();
}
window.onload = formfocus;
```

Didn't work either when placed at the bottom of the page(s).

I've tried searching for this problem and found;
[How can you autofocus on a form field in iPhone Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771785/how-can-you-autofocus-on-a-form-field-in-iphone-safari)

But there wasn't any helpful information returned either.

Now when I use the JavaScript and jQuery code posted above, it **does infact work on my web browsers** but again, **not on the iPad or iPhone** (I'm using an iPhone for testing with an incognito window each time to clear cache as a precaution).

Does anyone know a way to force the focus to a text input box on iPad/iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For usability reasons all the focus() functions are ignored by Safari in iPhone/iPad for usability reasons

[Quora](https://www.quora.com/Mobile-Safari-iPhone-or-iPad-with-JavaScript-how-can-I-launch-the-on-screen-keyboard)

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear enough, but I said it worked on my regular web browsers but not on the iPhone/iPad with the jQuery code in my original post. Thanks though!

Comment: So it really is impossible. That's frustrating. Guess he's going to have to click the box every time he wants to scan a product..

Comment: Apparently, makes sense why they do not allow it though. If you think my answer was helpful, please mark it as correct answer, thank you.