# How i focus input on iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, focus

hi i have this problem.

I want after click to focus input on `iphone`, with animation and focus input. It works everywhere just only `iphones` is the problem.
thx for everything.

```
$('.focusOnInput').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: "0px"
    }, 400, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("input#focusOnMe").focus();
        }, 100);

    });
});
```

Comment: Did a bit of research to discover `focus` functions are ignored by iOS devices - for usability concerns. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33830187/auto-focus-form-element-on-iphone-ipad - according to this stackoverflow article. Hope this helps!

Comment: i find something similar, but i hope there is some chance to make it :)

Comment: `focus()` is ignored when it is not a reaction to user's click, as described in answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/12204571/1235394

Comment: thx sorry for duplicate